# How to pass Jquery value to code behind in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

```
 $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {
            var msg = '';
            for (i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
                msg += "\n Width #" + i + " : " + $('#txtWidth' + i).val();
                msg += "\n Height #" + i + " : " + $('#txtHeight' + i).val();
                msg += "\n Length #" + i + " : " + $('#txtLength' + i).val();
                msg += "\n Weight #" + i + " : " + $('#txtWeight' + i).val();
            }
            alert(msg);
        });
```

This code return height,width,length and weight multiple time (With respect to conter).

[image]

I want to pass All this value to code behind file .And pass all value to this packeges.

```
                qurystr += "&packages[1][width]=" ";
                qurystr += "&packages[1][height]="";
                qurystr += "&packages[1][length]="";
                qurystr += "&packages[1][weight]="";
```

Please help.Thanks

Comment: Are you aware of the separation between server-side and client-side? Do you know about Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Hidden Fields to Save your List as Comma Separated Values

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hdf" />
```

In JS

```
$('<%#hdf.CliendID%>').value="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";

width,height,length,width,height,length....
```

Comment: @sonsha could you post new question

Comment: I am dragging data from "A" table to "B" .now display data of "B" in another table "C". I got one drag and drop row in "C" using hiddenfields. But I need each and every row from "B".

Comment: sorry for new question. I already reached to question limit in stackoverflow. thanks